# Two ajax updates with h:selectOneMenu f:ajax

Tags: ajax, jsf

> In short, if a component has been updated by Ajax, it can not launch new events Ajax

I have three h:selectOneMenu: A, B and C.
When I fire change event in A, then update the B h:selectOneMenu. 
When I fire change event in B, then update the C h:selectOneMenu.

The problem is that when the content of B h:selectOneMenu is updated, the ajax in B don't work and C never can't be updated.

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="A" value="#{paqueteBean.mes}" label="a">
<f:selectItem itemLabel="Seleccione..." itemValue="" />
<f:selectItem itemLabel="Enero" itemValue="ENERO" />
<f:selectItem itemLabel="Febrero" itemValue="FEBRERO" />
<f:ajax listener="#{paqueteBean.changeMes}" render="B" />
</h:selectOneMenu>

<h:selectOneMenu id="B" value="#{paqueteBean.origen}" label="b">
<f:selectItem itemLabel="Seleccione..." itemValue="" />
<f:selectItems value="#{paqueteBean.origenes}" />
<f:ajax listener="#{paqueteBean.changeOrigen}" render="C"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>

<h:selectOneMenu id="C" value="#{paqueteBean.zona}" label="c">
<f:selectItem itemLabel="Seleccione..." itemValue="" />
<f:selectItems value="#{paqueteBean.zonas}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

The ajax response is good, but simply don't work after the update:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<partial-response id="j_id1"><changes><update id="B"><![CDATA[<select id="B" name="b" size="1" onchange="mojarra.ab(this,event,'valueChange','@this','C')"> <option value="">Seleccione...</option>
    <option value="BUE">Ezeiza o Aeroparque</option>
</select>]]></update><update id="j_id1:javax.faces.ViewState:0"><![CDATA[-2984590031183218074:6198891110668113457]]></update></changes></partial-response>
```

UPDATE!

With PrimeFaces I have the same behavior:

```
<h:form id="filtro">
<p:selectOneMenu id="A" value="#{paqueteBean.mes}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Seleccione..." itemValue="" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Enero" itemValue="ENERO" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Febrero" itemValue="FEBRERO" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Marzo" itemValue="MARZO" />
    <p:ajax listener="#{paqueteBean.changeMes}" update="B" />
</p:selectOneMenu>

<p:selectOneMenu id="B" value="#{paqueteBean.origen}"
    disabled="#{empty paqueteBean.mes}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Seleccione..." itemValue="" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{paqueteBean.origenes}" />
    <p:ajax listener="#{paqueteBean.changeOrigen}" update="C"
        process="origen mesSalida" />
</p:selectOneMenu>

<p:selectOneMenu id="C" value="#{paqueteBean.zona}"
    disabled="#{empty paqueteBean.mes or empty paqueteBean.origen}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Seleccione..." itemValue="" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{paqueteBean.zonas}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

When I change some A values, the method in backing bean is fired, but when I change some B value, the method in backing bean is not fired.

The most strange is that for items that existed in B before the ajax update, the backing bean is called.

Backing Bean, nothing special:

```
    public void changeMes(){
    logger.debug("en changeMes el Mes es: " + this.mes);

    this.origenes = new HashMap<String, String>();
    this.origenes.put("Ezeiza o Aeroparque", "BUE");
}

public void changeOrigen(){
    logger.debug("Mes: " + this.mes);
    logger.debug("Origen" + this.origen);

    this.zonas = new HashMap<String, String>();
    this.zonas.put("Argentina", "AR");
    this.zonas.put("Brasil", "BR");
}

public void changeZona(){
    logger.debug("Mes: " + this.mes);
    logger.debug("Origen" + this.origen);
    logger.debug("Zona" + this.zona);

    this.destinos = new HashMap<>();
    this.destinos.put("Mar del Plata", "MDQ");
    this.destinos.put("Punta Lara", "LTA");
}
```

Comment: are B Items subItems of A, and C Items subItems of B? some thing like Country->City...etc?

Comment: So so, basically the selected item of A is used by filter un the posible result of B and the same with de B content to C content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

here is a working example:

Bean:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent;
import javax.faces.model.SelectItem;

@ManagedBean(name="myBean")
@SessionScoped
public class MyBean {

    private boolean bDisabled;
    private boolean cDisabled;

    private String selectedA;
    private String selectedB;
    private String selectedC;
    private ArrayList<SelectItem> aItems;
    private ArrayList<SelectItem> bItems;
    private ArrayList<SelectItem> cItems;

    public MyBean() {

    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        try{            

            this.bDisabled = new Boolean(true);
            this.cDisabled = new Boolean(true);

            this.aItems = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
            this.bItems = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
            this.cItems = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();

            this.aItems.add(new SelectItem("NONE", "---?"));
            this.aItems.add(new SelectItem("A1", "A 1"));
            this.aItems.add(new SelectItem("A1", "A 1"));
            this.aItems.add(new SelectItem("A1", "A 1"));

            this.bItems.add(new SelectItem("NONE", "---?"));
            this.cItems.add(new SelectItem("NONE", "---?"));

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }   

    public final void selectA(final AjaxBehaviorEvent event){
        try{
            System.out.println(this.selectedA);
            this.bItems.clear();
            this.bItems.add(new SelectItem("NONE", "---?"));
            if(this.selectedA.equals("NONE") ){
                this.setbDisabled(true);
                return;
            }
            this.bItems.add(new SelectItem("B1","B 1"));
            this.setbDisabled(false);
        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public final void selectB(final AjaxBehaviorEvent event){
        try{
            System.out.println(this.selectedB);
            this.cItems.clear();
            this.cItems.add(new SelectItem("NONE", "---?"));
            if(this.selectedB.equals("NONE") ){
                this.setcDisabled(true);
                return;
            }           
            this.cItems.add(new SelectItem("C1","C 1"));
            this.setcDisabled(false);
        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public final void selectC(final AjaxBehaviorEvent event){
        try{
            System.out.println(this.selectedC);
        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public String getSelectedA() {
        return selectedA;
    }

    public void setSelectedA(String selectedA) {
        this.selectedA = selectedA;
    }

    public String getSelectedB() {
        return selectedB;
    }

    public void setSelectedB(String selectedB) {
        this.selectedB = selectedB;
    }

    public String getSelectedC() {
        return selectedC;
    }

    public void setSelectedC(String selectedC) {
        this.selectedC = selectedC;
    }

    public ArrayList<SelectItem> getaItems() {
        return aItems;
    }

    public void setaItems(ArrayList<SelectItem> aItems) {
        this.aItems = aItems;
    }

    public ArrayList<SelectItem> getbItems() {
        return bItems;
    }

    public void setbItems(ArrayList<SelectItem> bItems) {
        this.bItems = bItems;
    }

    public ArrayList<SelectItem> getcItems() {
        return cItems;
    }

    public void setcItems(ArrayList<SelectItem> cItems) {
        this.cItems = cItems;
    }

    public boolean isbDisabled() {
        return bDisabled;
    }

    public void setbDisabled(boolean bDisabled) {
        this.bDisabled = bDisabled;
    }

    public boolean iscDisabled() {
        return cDisabled;
    }

    public void setcDisabled(boolean cDisabled) {
        this.cDisabled = cDisabled;
    }

}
```

XHTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      >
<h:head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Test</title>    
</h:head>
<body>
<f:view> 
<h:form id="dataForm">
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{myBean.selectedA}" style="width: 100%;">
    <f:selectItems value="#{myBean.aItems}" /> 
    <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form" listener="#{myBean.selectA}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>

<h:selectOneMenu disabled="#{myBean.bDisabled}" value="#{myBean.selectedB}" style="width: 100%;">
    <f:selectItems value="#{myBean.bItems}" /> 
    <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form" listener="#{myBean.selectB}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>

<h:selectOneMenu disabled="#{myBean.cDisabled}" value="#{myBean.selectedC}" style="width: 100%;">
    <f:selectItems value="#{myBean.cItems}" /> 
    <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form" listener="#{myBean.selectC}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>

</h:form>
</f:view>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, I have a h:form, and I try use execute with @this or the components ids and the Backing Bean looks like this one.

The first method "changeMes" is called.
If I add a <f:selectItem itemLabel="Other" itemValue="OTHER" /> in B h:selectOneMenu, when I change from "seleccione..." to "other" the method changeOrigen in backing bean also is called BUT if i use one of the items that are created automatically, the method in backing bean is no fired :(

Comment: i don't understand you, sorry, but would you update your question and post the part of your Bean where the update methods

Comment: @Sodero: i updated my answer, just try it as is, if it works, then change it as you would like. if it solves your problem, mark it please as accepted!

Comment: it is a good example and works. Now try you to change the @ SessionScoped for a @ RequestScoped and only upgrade one component at a time

Comment: @Sodero: if a bean is requestScoped, thats mean, by every call of any its properties, this bean will new created. also if you select A1, this will reset your bean, reseting the bean means B is disabled again though if you see it as enabled, but in fact its disabled, so selecting B will not work, because its disabled. you have to use SessionScoped or ViewScoped Bean. it will not work with Requestscope

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `<f:ajax/>` you can also use the PrimeFaces-Ajax-Element `<p:ajax>` which offers you a update-attribute:

```
<p:ajax update="elementID"/>
```

Another possibility I can recommend: Have you tried to put your SelectOneMenus in a `<h:form>`-Element? It looks like you didn't use a form. Do so, then you can always update the form in order to make the menues change. Worked good for me at my projects.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same mistake.
For the second selectonemenu i miss a setter.
In your code it was the setter for myBean.selectedB.
Check all your getter and setter. Maybe there is the problem

Comment: It would have caused a rather self-explaining exception.